# Sorting a dataframe by a regular expression in its names

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

In the following data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(1,6,6))

names(df) <- rownames (df) <- c("ABC.1cm", "ABC.2cm", "ABC.3cm", "DEF.1cm", "DEF.2cm", "DEF.3cm" )
```

how i can regroup the columns and rows so that "1cm", "2cm", "3cm" are grouped?

Desired output:

```
names(df) <- rownames (df) <- c("ABC.1cm", "DEF.1cm","ABC.2cm","DEF.2cm", "ABC.3cm", "DEF.3cm" )
df
        ABC.1cm DEF.1cm ABC.2cm DEF.2cm ABC.3cm DEF.3cm
ABC.1cm       1       1       1       1       1       1
DEF.1cm       1       1       1       1       1       1
ABC.2cm       1       1       1       1       1       1
DEF.2cm       1       1       1       1       1       1
ABC.3cm       1       1       1       1       1       1
DEF.3cm       1       1       1       1       1       1
```

Note: the "._cm" is actually there, but the prefixes vary. there also way more than the three values of "cm", (from 1cm to 29cm, so digit length may vary), and they appear in triplicates, rather than in duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordering by what ever comes after the last `.`.

```
correct_ord <- names(df)[order(sub(".+\\.", "", names(df)))]

df[correct_ord,correct_ord]

        ABC.1cm DEF.1cm ABC.2cm DEF.2cm ABC.3cm DEF.3cm
ABC.1cm       1       1       1       1       1       1
DEF.1cm       1       1       1       1       1       1
ABC.2cm       1       1       1       1       1       1
DEF.2cm       1       1       1       1       1       1
ABC.3cm       1       1       1       1       1       1
DEF.3cm       1       1       1       1       1       1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can match the digit in the `names`, strip the rest of the `names`, recall the digit via backreference `\\1`, and `order` the `names` accordingly:

```
names(df)[order(sub(".*(\\d+).*", "\\1", names(df)))]
[1] "ABC.1cm" "DEF.1cm" "ABC.2cm" "DEF.2cm" "ABC.3cm" "DEF.3cm"
```

Alternatively, you can use `str_extract`:

```
library(stringr)
names(df)[order(str_extract(names(df), "\\d+"))]
```